# Opencart remove counter in category top menu

Tags: php, opencart

I have the Sellya theme and i want to remove the counter next to product in category top menu.

See here: http://twsgs.com

I saw [here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=34222) at the bottom a solution and its look like that:

```
First change:

Open category.php with your preferred editor on => catalog/controller/module/category.php

Go to the line 49: 'name' => $child['name'] . ' (' . $product_total . ')'
Change it to: 'name' => $child['name'],// . ' (' . $product_total . ')'

Go to line 71: 'name' => $category['name'] . ' (' . $product_total . ')', 
Change it to: 'name' => $category['name'],// . ' (' . $product_total . ')',


Second change:

Open category.php on => catalog/controller/product/category.php

Go to line 137: 'name' => $result['name'] . ' (' . $product_total . ')',
Change it to: 'name' => $result['name'],// . ' (' . $product_total . ')',


Third change:

Open category.php on => catalog/controller/common/header.php

Go to line: 'name' => $child['name'] . ' (' . $product_total . ')';
Change it to: 'name' => $child['name'];// . ' (' . $product_total . ')';
```

but it worked partially.

also it has problems on the header.php (at the controller/common dir) and category.php (at the controller/product dir) so i insert my backup files instead.

My Opencart version is 1.5.5.1

How can i solve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an appropriate option to edit in the administration: `System` -> `Settings` -> edit Your store settings -> tab `Options` and find an option called `Category product count` or similar -> check the value **No** and save.

Or maybe this extension would be of use: [Category Product Count Removal](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=8237).

Comment: The admin suggestion is good. The fact that users keep suggesting extensions by terrible developers.. the extension library of vQmod and "freaky" not touching the core just puts me right off. The OpenCart extension library on the site is terrible. The graphics. The review system. The payment system. The quality of developers. The support. I recommend against linking there too. Thanks for the admin method.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid I agree with You about almost everything You said about OpenCart Extensions library. Except for developers and support - You can't paint everything with the same brush... My extensions are (I believe :-) ) 100% working, 100% tested, and I give a 100% support. So does Jay Gilford, e.g., and many others... If You hate OpenCart, it's community and everything around it so much, why are You using it, then? Go stuck with perfect Magento or PrestaShop and let's see how quickly You'll come back ;-)

Comment: I don't hate OpenCart. I am a HUGE supporter. I hate bloated systems like Magento and their now lame attempts to commercialise the product as if trying to come near DemandWare or the bigger players like Hybris or IBM WebSphere Commerce... It was just a small rant

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid So what is the reason You are complaining about me and yelling at me as if I were Your biggest pain in the ass? :-)